# Changing my thinking from a relational model to a document store (theory)

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database-schema, database

I'm still trying to wrap my head around how something like Mongo would be used in the wild.

Could someone please explain this to me (I know it's really simple)?

Okay, say I have a set of users which have a bunch of services, in an SQL database they would be stored like this:

Users table

```
| user_id | name | address |
|---------|------|---------|
| 1       | Zen  | 1 a St  |
|---------|------|---------|
```

Services

```
| service_id | user_id | service_type | cost |
|------------|---------|--------------|------|
| 1          | 1       | hosting      | 50   |
|------------|---------|--------------|------|
```

In Mongo would one store this within the user? so it is more like one would represent it programming with objects?

e.g.

```
User: 1
    Name: Zen
    Address: 1 a St
    Services:
        service 1
             type: hosting
             cost: 50
```

And if so, is there of having a "pointer" to value (for situations where more than one "thing" might "own" one other "thing", or the heirachy of data has relationships which require this?

How would one approach this problem with Mongo in mind, coming from a SQL background?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modeling can be more or less abstract.  In the world of SQL,  tables are just about the lowest level of abstraction you can use and still connect the data to the underlying subject matter.  Higher levels of abstraction are relational modeling and ER modeling.  "Higher" isn't a code word for "better".  each level of abstraction highlights certain features by glossing over other features.  What level is useful for your purposes depends on what you are trying to see more clearly.

One of the other responses mentions that Mongo supports nesting.  Nesting can be a way of encoding hierarchical relationships among data items, without imposing a lot of superstructure.  But without knowing Mongo, I can't tell you whether that's why the architects of Mongo provided nesting to their users.

Hierarchical relationships can be helpful or obstructive, depending on what you are trying to do.  For example, if you know the user, and you are trying to find all the services, the nesting structure proposed can be really easy to use, and possibly quite efficient.  But if you know the service, and you want to find all the users, you are in the world of hurt.

Overcoming the unfortunate side effects of hierarchical structures was one of the main reasons why the relational model  and relational databases gained the acceptance that they did.  But hierarchical relationships aren't always "bad".  In some cases, that's the best way to model data.

Getting back to your question,  you may want to compare SQL with Mongo at a higher level of abstraction than comparing tables to nesting structures.  I've told you what higher levels of abstraction to look for in connection with SQL.  Some other responder is going to have to tell you the same thing for Mongo.

Ultimately, if you keep going up the levels of abstraction,  you should find a model that is equally suited to both SQL and Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I've never used Mongo, but I have developed with a couple of NoSQL solutions.

In both Redis and CouchDB I store objects with a prefix-suffix style naming conventions.

Services ===
services.userid.1
services.userid.2

Users ===
users.userid.1
users.userid.2

To find the services for a user should be a breeze now. => services.user-name.wild-card

Comment: So you are still effectively making manual associations of the relationship between data? As in, you would still need to find the user's user id then find the services which have that ID assigned to them?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a seperate request I don't think, but I don't know enough about Mongo though. Currently this is indeed the only way I know how to operate with both Redis and CouchDB. I still need to crush some books as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Effective data modelling in MongoDB follows your app requirements and common use cases.  You can think of documents as similar to serialized objects; the MongoDB document format enables rich data structures including nesting.

It would be constructive to consider your application use cases first in order to plan how you would ideally like to query and manipulate data.  You do not have to predeclare your schema in MongoDB, which is helpful for prototyping.  The schema in MongoDB is often more akin to a data warehouse, where some data is intentionally denormalized to avoid joins and improve performance.  In fact, MongoDB does not support joins or subqueries :).

For relationships, there may also be some considerations if you are using an Object-Document Model or Data Mapper .. many of these provider helpers for relationships.

The traditional choice is whether to [embed or link](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) related data.

For your example you could still have a `users` collection and a `services` collection:

- If a user has_many services you would likely *embed* their list of services as an array within a user document.
- The user's services might include basic details such as the serviceID and name; the serviceID would be a unique ID that could be used to look up the full service definition in the services collection.  This would be *linking* to the services collection.  Note the MongoDB server does not support joins, so if you wanted to lookup a user and the full details for each service this would require multiple queries.

Related reading:

- [Designing MongoDB Schemas with Embedded, Non-Embedded and Bucket Structures](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/designing-mongodb-schemas-with-embedded-non-embedded-and-bucket-structures)
- [MongoDB: Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design)